# Помогите разобраться с ява скриптом

Tags: javascript

Я хочу сделать полезный плагин, который бы с сайта с объявлениями (olx.ua) вытягивал полезную информацию: первоначальная дата создания объявы, просмотр скрытых объявлений автора и так дальше. Все это не публикуется на сайте, но вся эта информация есть в переменной "window.**PRERENDERED_STATE**"
Например если я зайду на любую страницу с объявой
https://olx.ua/609229309
То там есть такой исходный код

```
...
<style data-emotion-css="2woq7...
Поддерживает множество рабочих режимов: точка доступа, Multi-SSID, клиент, ретранслятор...
<br />
Практически не испозовалась...
</div>
<script type="text/javascript" id="olx-init-config">
        window.__INIT_CONFIG__ = "{\"env\":\"production\",\"siteCode\":\"olxua...
        window.__FEATURE_FLAGS__ = ["b2c-pro-ads-editor","b2cProAdsImport","candidateProfileAuth",...
        window.__JSON_FEATURE_FLAGS__ = {"delivery-poland-enabled-categories":{"categories":[382,383,....
        window.__PRERENDERED_STATE__= {"ad":{"ad":{"id":711416844,"title":"Wi-fi точка доступа/...
        window.__TAURUS__= [];
</script>
<script id="__LOADABLE_REQUIRED_CHUNKS__" type="application/json">[54736,8754....
<script async data-chunk="olxeuweb.ad.view.desktop....
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Как мне с переменной window.PRERENDERED_STATE вытащить эти переменные: ad:id,ad:title и так далее???
Я уже задавал этот вопрос на stackoverflow, и 1 человек мне ответил, что
В данном случае window.PRERENDERED_STATE уже будет определенной переменной и можно к ней просто обратиться, например:

```
console.log(window.__PRERENDERED_STATE__)
```

Но я получаю такой ответ

```
{ad: null, categories: null, cookies: {…}}
ad: null
categories: null
cookies: {}
__proto__: Object
undefined
```

Почему? Почему ad=null, а не конкретному значению, как мне нужно?

Comment: Потому что содержимое этого элемента (`<script>` с id="olx-init-config") удаляется другими скриптами страницы. Ими же изменяется значение свойства `__PRERENDERED_STATE__`. И как ни печально это, но тем другим скриптам безразличны чьи-либо нужды - они просто выполняют свою работу.

Comment: Вот волшебный код для вызова с любой страницы того противного сайта, который так нетолерантен к воровству его контента: `console.log(JSON.parse((await fetch('https://www.olx.ua/609229309', { mode: 'cors' }).then(r => r.text())).match(/window.__PRERENDERED_STATE__\s*=\s*(.*)$/mi)[1].slice(0, -1)));` - сработает именно **на странице сайта** (из консоли браузера можно), но хз насчет "плагина". Еще стоит учесть, что при следующем обновлении противного сайта, этот волшебный код легко может превратиться в тыкву, так что поспеши... :)